# Can not get stdio.h to work in c# in visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I can not get stdio.h to work for my console application in visual studio 2017. I have researched for about 3 days now and have found nothing useful. All of the help topics I could find were for c++. It does work when I make a c++ console application but not when I create a c# console application. [stdio.h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbMkf.png) [This is the error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkCfJ.png)
I am trying to learn c# and I can't figure out how to get this to work so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Because C# is *entirely* different from C++. C# has no concept/idea of headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**stdio** is the standard input/output library for C. The **iostream** is the standard input/output library for C++. The "stdio.h" is the header file and "stdio.c" have the implementation. You should not try to use it in a diferent language (C#). It's like trying to use node modules (Javascript) in Perl, Php or Java.

Please note that **C++** was created in 1983-85 by Bjarne Stroustrup as an Object Oriented evolution of the **C** language (Designed in 1972 by Dennis Ritchie).

**C#** (C sharp) was created in 2000 by Microsoft (with the .net framework). It was influenced by **C++** and **Java**.

You can have an Visual C++ project (and solution) in Visual Studio 2017. Other languages supported are C#, VB.net, F# or Python.

Comment: It's actually the standard I/O library for C. Idiomatic C++ would use e.g. `iostream` instead.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, it's because you don't use header files in C#.

The closest equivalent concept is the using directive, which allows you to reference code from other namespaces.

Microsoft has great documentation about this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive

Additionally, if you want to look into the contents of the various namespaces of the framework to know which to include, you should check out the API Browser: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?view=netframework-4.7.1